# What is Macintosh OSX equivilent to Windows WM_POWERBROADCAST message

Tags: macos

I'm a Windows developer, but my team counterpart on the Mac side has asked me for help with an issue our Mac client has when the user wakes up his computer from hibernation.

I handle the wake up situation in our Windows client using the Windows WM_POWERBROADCAST message.  This is a message that Windows sends to applications whenever there is a change in the power state of the hardware (on/off/suspend/resume).

Does OSX support a similar notification to tell running applications that the computer is suspending, resuming, or powering up or down?

TIA.

Comment: What is the equivalent to MSDN for Mac development? That's an honest question, I simply don't know that answer.

Comment: @David: there is online documentation at http://developer.apple.com, and this is also available locally from within the Xcode IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NSWorkspace`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a bunch of notifications you can listen for.

Sorry, edited because the first post was completely wrong. `NSWorkspace` doesn't use the default notification center for notifications. This is copied mostly out of Apple's docs.

```
NSNotificationCenter *notCenter;

notCenter = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];
[notCenter addObserver:self
              selector:@selector(didWake:)
                  name:NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification
                object:nil];
```